# How to speed up the program with thread pool in python3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, threadpool

```
what kind of thread or how many thread should I use, if I doing the following?
```

My question is like this:

Thread 1 doing the process: As long as Last name in line_1(first line of base_file) can be matched in row_1-row_end( every line in the huge_file), write line_1 and several rows in row_1-row_end if any matched.

Thread 2 doing the process: As long as Last name in line_2(first line of base_file) can be matched in row_1-row_end( every line in the huge_file), write line_2 and several rows in row_1-row_end if any matched.

Thread 3 doing the process: As long as Last name in line_3(first line of base_file) can be matched in row_1-row_end( every line in the huge_file), write line_3 and several rows in row_1-row_end if any matched.

........

Thread 100 doing the process: As long as Last name in line_100(first line of base_file) can be matched in row_1-row_end( every line in the huge_file), write line_100 and several rows in row_1-row_end if any matched.

These 100 threads or more all start at the same time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have normal code to do the step-by-step job which is a nested for loop but it takes me very long time to do process my code.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import csv
import codecs
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    with open("Director_1980.csv", 'wt', newline = '') as f3:
        writer = csv.writer(f3)    
        f2list = []
        with open("contribDB_1980final.csv", 'rt') as f2: ## This file is a big file
            reader = csv.reader(f2)    
            for row in reader: 
                f2list.append(row)

        with codecs.open("director.csv", "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fdata:
            for line in fdata:
                line = line.split("|")
                lName = line[5]
                fName = line[1] 
                mName = line[2]
                employer = line[6]


                for row in f2list: 
                    lName2 = row[7]
                    fName2 = row[8]
                    mName2 = row[9]
                    employer2 = row[20]

                    list1 = []
                    list2 = []
                    if fuzz.token_set_ratio(lName, lName2) == 100:
                        count2 = count2 + 1  
                        print(count2)
                        #print(count2 )
                        lName_ratio = 100
                        fName_ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(fName, fName2)
                        mName_ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(mName, mName2)
                        employer_ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(employer, employer2)
                        new_line = line + row
                        new_line.insert(16, lName_ratio)
                        new_line.insert(18, fName_ratio) 
                        new_line.insert(20, mName_ratio)
                        new_line.insert(32, employer_ratio)

                        writer.writerow(new_line)
```

Comment: you are using up a lot of memory when populating `f2list`. why not handle one row of `contribDB_1980final.csv` at the time instead of reading them all to memory?

Comment: What you mean to get one row of contribDB_1980final.csv. How can I get to that?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. your loops are nested... i'd have suggested to reverse the order of the iteration over `contribDB_1980final.csv` and `director.csv` but i realized just now, that this will not work. sorry.